# Installation doesn't work on a Lenovo IdeaPad g570

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2

the issue i'm having is that every time i try to install ubuntu on my BRAND NEW lenovo it just crashes and one timr CORRUPTED GRUB it's getting extremely annoying and i need help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a release problem, try to install another Ubuntu release.

A co-worker has a Lenovo (not the same as you) and he installed the last Ubuntu release with the same problem as you. He tried with the 11.10 version and everything was fine, and then `apt-get dist-upgrade` and everything is still running fine.

I hope this help!

Comment: Please note that it is advisable to run `sudo apt-get update` before running `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, or `sudo apt-get install ...`. (`sudo apt-get update` updates information about what packages are available in what versions and from where--if you don't run it, you might not really be getting the latest versions in an upgrade or installation operation.)

Comment: You may need to fiddle with the BIOS settings - BUT my G570 works fine (???) , so don't give up.